# ngSubmit event not raised

Tags: angular

I have the below simple angular template driven form which does not work (ngSubmit event does not seems to raise) when i use the the Angular material component, but the same does work when using bootstrap styled controls...The data model binding works in both cases, but with material components, the "authenticateUser" method is not called. I am sure missing something here....Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class ="login-container">
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="authenticateUser(loginForm)" >
    <div>
        <mat-form-field >
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"  required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>  
</form>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
<div style="margin-top: 5%">
    <a routerLink="/changepassword">Change Password</a>
</div>
```

Angular Generated Form Model : {{loginForm.value | json}}

Thanks

jcm

Comment: try to add button type="submit" and place the button inside the form tag

Comment: Thank you, it works now with your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Button type should be `submit` and it should be inside the form

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="authenticateUser(loginForm)" >
    <div>
        <mat-form-field >
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"  required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>  

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Sachila. It works now, though I dont have to add the type =Submit.

Comment: form need to identify which button to trigger if it has more than one button. So we need to specify a type submit to one button

Answer (score 0):

You `submit` `button` must be inside the `form`

```
<div class ="login-container">
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="authenticateUser(loginForm)" >
    <div>
        <mat-form-field >
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"  required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>  
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" >Login</button>
</form>

<div style="margin-top: 5%">
    <a routerLink="/changepassword">Change Password</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sunil, it works when the button is placed within the <form>, and without the type=submit

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your .html,

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)" id="ngForm">
  ....
</form>

<button form="ngForm" mat-icon-button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
```

In your .ts,

```
request : any;

onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
    this.request = this.myForm.value;
    if (form.value.id != null) {
      this.service
        .put(this.request )
        .subscribe(
          () => {
          },
          err => {
            console.log("Error Occurred." + JSON.stringify(err));
          }
        );
    } else {
      this.service
        .create(this.request)
        .subscribe(
          () => {
            this.snackBarService.success("Successfully saved.");
          },
          err => {
            console.log("Error Occurred" + JSON.stringify(err));
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Like the idea of keeping the button outside the <form> tag.

Comment: @JCMenon great !